# Error while calling WebService Using CXF 2.3.3Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element

Tags: java, web-services, apache, cxf, unmarshalling

I'm getting the following error when I call the WebService using CXF 2.2.3. The error occurs when the WebService returns the data.

> Unmarshalling Error: unexpected element ( uri:"http://service.claimservice.hospital.www.wcb.ab.in", local:"accidentAddress"). Expected elements are <{http://domain.claimservice.hospital.www.wcb.ab.in}employerContactInfo>,<{http://domain.claimservice.hospital.www.wcb.ab.in}accidentCountry>,<{http://domain.claimservice.hospital.www.wcb.ab.in}denialReason>,<{http://domain.claimservice.hospital.www.wcb.ab.in}workerContactInfo>,<{http://domain.claimservice.hospital.www.wcb.ab.in}accidentPostalCode>,<{http://domain.claimservice.hospital.www.wcb.ab.in}entitlementDecisionDate>,

Can anyone tel me if it is possible to get rid of this error by changing my wsdl?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the request contains an element in the XML with a fully-qualified name of `{http://service.claimservice.hospital.www.wcb.ab.in}accidentAddress` in a location for which only the elements on the 'Expected elements' list are valid.

This is based on the unmarshaller's context which is, ultimately, based on the schema(s) from which the datatypes were read (should be the schemas presented/imported into the WSDL 'types' section).

Based on the information in the question, the response pipeline is the problem, so the server-side marshaller and client-side unmarshaller are out of sync (were created from different schema(s)).

Suggested Troubleshooting (assuming use of a marshaller object on the server-side):

1. Capture the XML for the problematic message.
2. Determine if the XML is consistent with what is presented in the types section of the WSDL.
3. IF the XML is compliant with the WSDL, then the likely issue is that the client-side unmarshaller has been supplied with datatypes that are different than those presented in the WSDL.
4. IF the XML is not compliant with the WSDL, the server-side XML marshaller is creating an incorrect message (or it is creating a correct message and the WSDL is incorrect...it happens).  In this case, the marshaller may have been created against outdated datatypes.

If not using a marshaller object and instead creating the service response by hand, the problem is that the accidentAddress element is being created when it is not a valid part of the XML message or it is a valid part of the message but in the wrong location relative to containing element.

This is a little long-winded, but hopefully contains enough information to help out.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved the problem  URL url = new URL(uri);
Service service = Service.create(url, serviceName);
Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(portName,SOAPMessage.class,Service.Mode.MESSAGE);
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();                                       Copy the SOAP request XML part, Create a new ByteArrayInputStream object by passing that XML string as bytes.Create a SOAPMessage object from MessageFactory and then call the invoke method of Dispatch by passing the object of SOAPMessage this will give you the webservice response in XML